# MongoDB - Move some fields from the array into another array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this simplified MongoDB document and would like to change something because there is quite a lot of redundant data. This field "activeUsersLookup" is the result of aggregation which returns data I'd like to put inside the first `users` array.

First id:
`"_id": "80b1565a-faf4-4e68-9bd6-8344060e8d3a"` matches
`id` from `activeUsersLookup` the same story is with user IDs.

```
[{
  "_id": "80b1565a-faf4-4e68-9bd6-8344060e8d3a",
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": "eaa946da-2708-443e-ab4c-b6db357050ca",
      "lastactive": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1637922656000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "4972ba13-6f4e-4943-be07-15802e22e0dd",
      "lastactive": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1653286066000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6c4a62ce-c6c6-430f-a0cd-d348ec77dbb2",
      "lastactive": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1558623982000"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "activeUsersLookup": [
    {
      "_id": "80b1565a-faf4-4e68-9bd6-8344060e8d3a",
      "users": [
        {
          "_id": "eaa946da-2708-443e-ab4c-b6db357050ca",
          "activities": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": "6c4a62ce-c6c6-430f-a0cd-d348ec77dbb2",
          "activities": 1
        }
      ],
      "sumOfActivities": 3
    }
  ]
}]
```

So more or less the final document should look like this:

```
[{
  "_id": "80b1565a-faf4-4e68-9bd6-8344060e8d3a",
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": "eaa946da-2708-443e-ab4c-b6db357050ca",
      "lastactive": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1637922656000"
        }
      },
      "activities": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "4972ba13-6f4e-4943-be07-15802e22e0dd",
      "lastactive": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1653286066000"
        }
      },
      "activities": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "6c4a62ce-c6c6-430f-a0cd-d348ec77dbb2",
      "lastactive": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1558623982000"
        }
      },
      "activities": 1
    },
    "sumOfActivities": 3
  ]
}]
```

I've tried with:

```
{
    $addFields: {
      'licenses.activities': '$activeUsersLookup.users.activities'
    }
}
```

But this gives me an empty array so I must be doing something wrong.
The next stage would be to sum all those `activities` as `sumOfActivities` and the last stage would be unset `activeUsersLookup`.

What magic tricks must I do to have the needed result? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the expected result you posted for the `"sumOfActivities": 3` in the `users` array is valid.

Assume that you are trying to achieve the result as below:

```
[{
  "_id": "80b1565a-faf4-4e68-9bd6-8344060e8d3a",
  "users": [...],
  "sumOfActivities": 3
}]
```

The query is a bit long:

1. `$set` - Set `activeUsersLookup` field as object.

   1.1. `$first` - Get the first document from *1.2*.

   1.2. `$filter` - Filter document(s) from `activeUsersLookup` by matching `_id` for the document in `activeUsersLookup` with `_id` (root document).
2. `$set`

   2.1. - Set `users` array.

   2.1.1. `$map` - Iterate the documents in `users` array and return a new array.

   2.1.2. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current documents with the documents with `activities` field.

   2.1.3. `$ifNull` - Set `activities` as 0 if no result returned from *2.1.4*.

   2.1.4. `$getField` - Get the `activities` field from the result *2.1.5*.

   2.1.5. `$first` - Get the first document from the result *2.1.6*.

   2.1.6. `$filter` - Filter the `activeUsersLookup.users` documents by matching `_id` for the document (`users` array) with `_id` for the current document.

   2.2. Set `sumOfActivities` field.
3. `$unset` - Remove `activeUsersLookup` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      activeUsersLookup: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$activeUsersLookup",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this._id",
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $map: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$user",
              {
                activities: {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    {
                      "$getField": {
                        "field": "activities",
                        "input": {
                          $first: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$activeUsersLookup.users",
                              cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$this._id",
                                  "$$user._id"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      sumOfActivities: "$activeUsersLookup.sumOfActivities"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "activeUsersLookup"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gzNjIoJYx8l)

Comment: Works, thank you very much! You should get Nobel prize in category "mongodb queries" ;)